# Is it possible to have multiple variable names (not numeric) in column using the case_when function or by using a different function

Tags: r, dplyr

Here is a chunk of my data frame looks like this (called cap1)

```r
structure(list(date = c("3/21/2020", "3/21/2020", "3/22/2020", 
 "3/23/2020", "3/23/2020", "3/23/2020", "3/23/2020", "3/23/2020", 
 "3/23/2020", "3/23/2020", "3/23/2020", "3/24/2020", "3/24/2020", 
 "3/25/2020", "3/25/2020", "3/25/2020", "3/26/2020", "3/26/2020", 
 "3/29/2020", "3/29/2020", "3/29/2020", "3/29/2020", "3/29/2020", 
 "3/29/2020", "3/29/2020", "3/29/2020", "3/29/2020", "3/29/2020", 
 "3/30/2020", "3/30/2020"), Site = c("Jag", "Jag", "Jag", "Jag", 
 "Jag", "Jag", "Jag", "Jag", "Jag", "Jag", "Jag", "Bla", "Bla",  "Bla",
 "Bla", "Bla", "Bla", "Bla", "Lon", "Lon", "Lon", "Lon",  "Lon", "Lon",
 "Lon", "Lon", "Lon", "Lon", "Lon", "Lon"), Column1 = c("JagB60", 
 "JagB57", "JagB27", "JagA55", "JagC52", "JagB53", "JagB85", "JagC66", 
 "JagB79", "JagB37", "JagA81", "BlaC64", "BlaB81", "BlaC77", "BlaC76", 
 "BlaC11", "BlaC64", "BlaC19", "LonB11", "LonC73", "LonC16", "LonC26", 
 "LonB9", "LonC80", "LonB55", "LonB2", "LonB70", "LonC24", "LonB81", 
 "LonC67"), Species = c("Per m. ", "Per m. ", "Mic o.", "Mic o.",  "Per
 m. ", "Per m. ", "Per m. ", "Per m. ", "Per m. ", "Per m. ",  "Per l. 
 ", "Per m. ", "Per m. ", "Per m. ", "Per m. ", "Per m. ",  "Per m. ",
 "Per m. ", "Per m. ", "Per m. ", "Per m. ", "Per m. ",  "Per m. ",
 "Per m. ", "Per m. ", "Per m. ", "Per m. ", "Per m. ",  "Per m. ",
 "Per m. "), PIT.Tag = c(9460838L, 9460784L, 1234573L,  9460831L,
 9460845L, 9460838L, 9460794L, 9460785L, 9460784L, 9460781L,  9460777L,
 9460780L, 2055339L, 9460813L, 9460782L, 9460786L, 9460782L,  9460786L,
 9460810L, 9460834L, 9460795L, 9460798L, 9460788L, 9460842L,  9460822L,
 2055397L, 2055377L, 2055393L, 2055380L, 2055384L), 
     Gender = c("M", "F", "M", "F", "F", "M", "F", "F", "F", "M", 
     "F", "M", "F", "F", "F", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
     "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F")), row.names = c(NA,  30L), class = "data.frame")
```

I need to create a column that is called session, that had names associated with the date column. So if the date is 3/21/2020, under the session column it would be called Jag_1. I originally had a session column that just labeled the different dates by a number (1, 2, 3, 4 5, 6) but that no longer works for my analysis but since I have that code would there be a way to update to what I now need. Here is what that code looks like.

```
cap1 %<>% 
  mutate(Session = case_when(date %in%        
                               c("3/21/2020", "3/22/2020", "3/23/2020",      
                                 "3/24/2020", "3/25/2020", "3/26/2020",
                                 "3/29/2020", "3/30/2020", "3/31/2020",
                                 "4/1/2020", "4/2/2020","4/3/2020")~ 1,
                             date %in% c("4/9/2020", "4/10/2020", "4/11/2020",       
                                         "4/6/2020", "4/7/2020", "4/8/2020",
                                         "4/14/2020", "4/15/2020", "4/16/2020",
                                         "4/17/2020", "4/18/2020", "4/19/2020")~ 2,
                             date %in% c("4/28/2020", "4/29/2020", "4/30/2020", 
                                         "4/23/2020", "4/24/2020", "4/25/2020", 
                                         "5/1/2020", "5/2/2020", "5/3/2020", 
                                         "5/6/2020", "5/7/2020", "5/8/2020")~ 3,
                             date %in% c("5/15/2020", "5/16/2020", "5/17/2020",
                                         "5/10/2020", "5/11/2020", "5/12/2020",
                                         "5/18/2020", "5/19/2020", "5/20/2020",
                                         "5/24/2020", "5/25/2020", "5/26/2020")~4,
                             date %in% c("6/1/2020", "6/2/2020", "6/3/2020",
                                         "5/27/2020", "5/28/2020", "5/29/2020",
                                         "6/4/2020", "6/5/2020", "6/6/2020",
                                         "6/9/2020", "6/10/2020", "6/11/2020")~5, 
                             date %in% c("6/17/2020", "6/18/2020", "6/19/2020",
                                         "6/12/2020", "6/13/2020", "6/14/2020",
                                         "6/20/2020", "6/21/2020", "6/22/2020",
                                         "6/24/2020", "6/25/2020", "6/26/2020")~6,
```

I tried changing the code to see if it would work but so far it hasn't for me. I get errors saying it cannot find Jag_1 or it just won't run. This is what my attempt looked like.

```
cap1 %<>% 
  mutate(Session = case_when(date %in%         
                               c("3/21/2020", "3/22/2020", "3/23/2020")~ Jag_1,      
                                 c("3/24/2020", "3/25/2020", "3/26/2020")~Bla_1,
                                 c("3/29/2020", "3/30/2020", "3/31/2020")~Lon_1,
                                 c("4/1/2020", "4/2/2020","4/3/2020")~ Pat_1,
                             date %in% c("4/9/2020", "4/10/2020", "4/11/2020")~Pat_2,       
                                        c("4/6/2020", "4/7/2020", "4/8/2020")~Jag_2,
                                         c("4/14/2020", "4/15/2020", "4/16/2020")~Bla_2,
                                         c("4/17/2020", "4/18/2020", "4/19/2020")~ Lon_2
```

For clarification, I would like to create a data frame that looks like this.  on the date.

```
 date Site Column1 Species PIT.Tag Gender         Session
    1 3/21/2020  Jag  JagB60 Per m.  9460838      M   Jag_1
    2 3/21/2020  Jag  JagB57 Per m.  9460784      F   Jag_1
    3 3/22/2020  Jag  JagB27  Mic o. 1234573      M   Jag_1
    4 3/23/2020  Jag  JagA55  Mic o. 9460831      F   Jag_1
    5 3/23/2020  Jag  JagC52 Per m.  9460845      F   Jag_1
    6 3/23/2020  Jag  JagB53 Per m.  9460838      M   Jag_1
    7  3/23/2020  Jag  JagB85  Per m.  9460794      F Jag_1
8  3/23/2020  Jag  JagC66  Per m.  9460785      F     Jag_1
9  3/23/2020  Jag  JagB79  Per m.  9460784      F     Jag_1
10 3/23/2020  Jag  JagB37  Per m.  9460781      M     Jag_1
11 3/23/2020  Jag  JagA81 Per l.   9460777      F     Jag_1
12 3/24/2020  Bla  BlaC64  Per m.  9460780      M     Bla_1
13 3/24/2020  Bla  BlaB81  Per m.  2055339      F     Bla_1
14 3/25/2020  Bla  BlaC77  Per m.  9460813      F     Bla_1
15 3/25/2020  Bla  BlaC76  Per m.  9460782      F     Bla_1
16 3/25/2020  Bla  BlaC11  Per m.  9460786      M     Bla_1
17 3/26/2020  Bla  BlaC64  Per m.  9460782      F     Bla_1
18 3/26/2020  Bla  BlaC19  Per m.  9460786      M     Bla_1
19 3/29/2020  Lon  LonB11  Per m.  9460810      M     Lon_1
20 3/29/2020  Lon  LonC73  Per m.  9460834      M     Lon_1
21 3/29/2020  Lon  LonC16  Per m.  9460795      M     Lon_1
22 3/29/2020  Lon  LonC26  Per m.  9460798      M     Lon_1
23 3/29/2020  Lon   LonB9  Per m.  9460788      F     Lon_1
24 3/29/2020  Lon  LonC80  Per m.  9460842      M     Lon_1
25 3/29/2020  Lon  LonB55  Per m.  9460822      M     Lon_1
26 3/29/2020  Lon   LonB2  Per m.  2055397      M     Lon_1
27 3/29/2020  Lon  LonB70  Per m.  2055377      F     Lon_1
28 3/29/2020  Lon  LonC24  Per m.  2055393      M     Lon_1
29 3/30/2020  Lon  LonB81  Per m.  2055380      M     Lon_1
30 3/30/2020  Lon  LonC67  Per m.  2055384      F     Lon_1
```

Comment: Please post `dput(cap1)` instead of (or in addition to) pasting its columnar representation.  It's easier to load into an R environment that way.  Also please describe your desired output and, preferably, post what it looks like - especially if the code to get your desired output is throwing an error, it's harder to understand what your goals are.

Comment: This may just be a syntax issue though - wrap `Jag_1` etc in quotes, making them strings.  `date %in%  c("3/21/2020", "3/22/2020", "3/23/2020")~ "Jag_1"`

Comment: even with using dput the data frame is way too long to post or even scroll through on the r console. Is there a different way to show you what the data frame looks like?

Comment: Your goal in providing a [mcve] is to give the minimum amount of data necessary to reproduce the problem.  You can either do something like `dput(head(cap1, x))`, where `x` is some reasonable number, or hand-pick a representative sample that covers at least some of the `Session` values needed to demonstrate a solution.

Comment: Okay I updated the post on your suggestions, thank you for your patience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**
Looking at your `case_when` examples, it seems that all `_2` sessions happen after a certain date.
If that's true, you can just create an `index` column based on that date crossover, and then combine the `Site` and `index` strings together for `session`.
Like this:

```r
cap1 %>%
  group_by(Site) %>%
  mutate(date = lubridate::mdy(date),
         index = if_else(date < "2020-04-09", 1, 2),
         session = paste(Site, index, sep = "_"))
```

**Previous answer**
You have the right idea, your syntax is just a bit off.  Use `date %in%` on each `case_when` case, and quote your labels:

```r
cap1 %>% 
  mutate(Session = case_when(
    date %in% c("3/21/2020", "3/22/2020", "3/23/2020") ~ "Jag_1",     
    date %in% c("3/24/2020", "3/25/2020", "3/26/2020") ~ "Bla_1",
    date %in% c("3/29/2020", "3/30/2020", "3/31/2020") ~ "Lon_1",
    date %in% c("4/1/2020", "4/2/2020","4/3/2020") ~ "Pat_1",
    date %in% c("4/9/2020", "4/10/2020", "4/11/2020") ~ "Pat_2",   
    date %in% c("4/6/2020", "4/7/2020", "4/8/2020") ~ "Jag_2",
    date %in% c("4/14/2020", "4/15/2020", "4/16/2020") ~ "Bla_2",
    date %in% c("4/17/2020", "4/18/2020", "4/19/2020") ~ "Lon_2"
    )
  )
```

Output:

```r
        date Site Column1    Species PIT.Tag Gender Session
1  3/21/2020  Jag  JagB60    Per m.  9460838      M   Jag_1
2  3/21/2020  Jag  JagB57    Per m.  9460784      F   Jag_1
3  3/22/2020  Jag  JagB27     Mic o. 1234573      M   Jag_1
4  3/23/2020  Jag  JagA55     Mic o. 9460831      F   Jag_1
5  3/23/2020  Jag  JagC52  Per\n m.  9460845      F   Jag_1
6  3/23/2020  Jag  JagB53    Per m.  9460838      M   Jag_1
7  3/23/2020  Jag  JagB85    Per m.  9460794      F   Jag_1
8  3/23/2020  Jag  JagC66    Per m.  9460785      F   Jag_1
9  3/23/2020  Jag  JagB79    Per m.  9460784      F   Jag_1
10 3/23/2020  Jag  JagB37    Per m.  9460781      M   Jag_1
11 3/23/2020  Jag  JagA81 Per l. \n  9460777      F   Jag_1
12 3/24/2020  Bla  BlaC64    Per m.  9460780      M   Bla_1
13 3/24/2020  Bla  BlaB81    Per m.  2055339      F   Bla_1
14 3/25/2020  Bla  BlaC77    Per m.  9460813      F   Bla_1
15 3/25/2020  Bla  BlaC76    Per m.  9460782      F   Bla_1
16 3/25/2020  Bla  BlaC11    Per m.  9460786      M   Bla_1
17 3/26/2020  Bla  BlaC64    Per m.  9460782      F   Bla_1
18 3/26/2020  Bla  BlaC19    Per m.  9460786      M   Bla_1
19 3/29/2020  Lon  LonB11    Per m.  9460810      M   Lon_1
20 3/29/2020  Lon  LonC73    Per m.  9460834      M   Lon_1
21 3/29/2020  Lon  LonC16    Per m.  9460795      M   Lon_1
22 3/29/2020  Lon  LonC26    Per m.  9460798      M   Lon_1
23 3/29/2020  Lon   LonB9    Per m.  9460788      F   Lon_1
24 3/29/2020  Lon  LonC80    Per m.  9460842      M   Lon_1
25 3/29/2020  Lon  LonB55    Per m.  9460822      M   Lon_1
26 3/29/2020  Lon   LonB2    Per m.  2055397      M   Lon_1
27 3/29/2020  Lon  LonB70    Per m.  2055377      F   Lon_1
28 3/29/2020  Lon  LonC24    Per m.  2055393      M   Lon_1
29 3/30/2020  Lon  LonB81    Per m.  2055380      M   Lon_1
30 3/30/2020  Lon  LonC67    Per m.  2055384      F   Lon_1
```